# Import Oracle data dump and overwrite existing data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle dmp file and I need to import data into a table. 
The data in the dump contains new rows and few updated rows.
I am using import command and IGNORE=Y, so it imports all the new rows well. But it doesn't import/overwrite the existing rows (it shows a warning of unique key constraint violated).
Is there some option to make the import UPDATE the existing rows with new data?

Answer (score 7):

No. If you were using data pump then you could use the `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=TRUNCATE` option to remove all existing rows and import everything from the dump file, but as you want to update existing rows and leave any rows not in the new file alone - i.e. not delete them (I think, since you only mention updating, though that isn't clear) - that might not be appropriate. And as your dump file is from the old `exp` tool rather than `expdp` that's moot anyway, unless you can re-export the data.

If you do want to delete existing rows that are not in the dump then you could truncate all the affected tables before importing. But that would be a separate step that you'd have to perform yourself, its not something `imp` will do for you; and the tables would be empty for a while, so you'd have to have downtime to do it.

Alternatively you could import into new staging tables - in a different schema since`imp` doesn't support renaming either - and then use those to `merge` the new data into the real tables. That may be the least disruptive approach. You'd still have to design and write all the `merge` statements though. There's no built-in way to do this automatically.

Comment: You can also use TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE that will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can import into temp table and then do record recon by joining with it.

Use impdp option REMAP_TABLE to load existing file into temp table.

```
impdp .... REMAP_TABLE=TMP_TABLE_NAME
```

when load is done run MERGE statement on existing table from temp table.